# File encrypted with OpenSSL cannot be decrypted with LibreSSL

Tags: encryption, linux, openssl, macos

First off, please don't turn this question into a LibreSSL vs OpenSSL holy war! I'm just trying to understand the **functional** differences between them, nothing more.

I originally asked [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1768666/469529) but I think it's more relevant here.

I've encrypted a file on an Amazon Linux 2 VM using the default installed OpenSSL version (OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips) like so:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -out ~/my_file.txt.enc -pass pass:[redacted]
```

However when decrypting the file on OSX using the default installed OpenSSL version (LibreSSL 3.3.6) using the command below, I keep getting "Bad Decrypt".

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in ~/my_file.txt.enc -pass pass:[redacted] > my_file.txt
```

Firstly, are there differences between the decryption process for `aes-256-cbc` on LibreSSL and on OpenSSL, or have I got something else wrong in the decryption process?

Secondly, if there are differences in the encryption/decryption process is it possible to run both LibreSSL and OpenSSL on OSX?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1679471/libressl-aes-encryption-incompatible-with-openssl) SuperUser question?

Comment: I haven't. I've tried manually specifying the digest algo to use for the decrypt but still get "bad decrypt" for md5 and sha256.

Comment: See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/103622/27923).